# Can't call my iterator function?

Tags: java, iterator, implements

I'm not sure why my `getIterator()` function I made isn't working correctly. Below are the 3 classes I have and they implement each other. However specifically under the class `MapView` at the line `Iterator gameObjects = gap.getCollection().getIterator();` the `.getIterator()` isn't getting the iterator from `GameObjectCollection` class like it should.

EDIT: The error it gives me is `The method getIterator() is undefined for the type Object`

Comment: i don't understand what is the problem, you get an error? a null? or what?

Comment: Sorry should've put the error in there. It gives me a `The method getIterator() is undefined for the type Object`

Comment: Shouldn't `GameWorldProxy` be a `GameObjectCollection` instead? That is the class you have shown which has the getIterator method in it. Does your class `GameWorldProxy` also have a getIterator method?

Comment: GameObjectCollection implements Collection, post GameWorldProxy too.

Comment: @Takendarkk that's what I thought too but I asked one of my classmates and he had it set up just like me, but his worked.

But I'm gonna update the OP with `GameWorldProxy`

Comment: Alright, the object you are calling getIterator on is an instance of GameWorldProxy which _does not_ have a getIterator method. Did your classmate's GameWorldProxy also implement your Collection interface? In that case his would work because his class _would_ have this method in it.

Comment: Nope, his GameWorldProxy doesn't implement the Collection interface that's why I'm confused why it works. @Takendarkk

Comment: Without seeing his code it is pretty hard to tell exactly what the difference is between his and yours, but I can tell you 100% sure that if the class doesn't have the method in it, you can't call it. End of story.

Comment: @Takendarkk I agree with you. When I hover over the `.getIterator()` in Eclipse it shows `package.GameObjectCollection.getIterator()` then when I hover over `.getCollection()` it shows `package.GameWorldProxy.getCollection()` on his part. Not sure if this helps, maybe it can clear things up a bit on why his works and mine doesn't.

Comment: You get that error because GameWorldProxy's getCollection() returns type "Object". So there's no getIterator() on type Object. If you're sure it returns a different type, either change the return type (cast if needed) or cast the value you get in response and then call getIterator() on the correct type.

Comment: I figured it out, it was a simple mismatch of method names I had it on of the proxy strategies I used.